# Can cycles Wireframe Input be coerced into displaying Tris, Quads and Ngons

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, wireframe

**edit 2 years later**: Here is [an alternative answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/9274/47) that meets the desired end-result using FreeStyle.

---

Is there a way to make the *wireframe input* show the geometry as BMesh polygons instead of the raw triangulated mesh? The example below displays the wireframe of a mesh in edit mode (as you can see it doesn't have any triangles).

[image]

When I render the mesh it appears triangulated, but being able to show quads and ngons (instead of only tris) would be more useful to me.

[image]

Comment: Which wireframe material is this? Can you link to it please?

Comment: it's a mix of `wireframe input` and `ambient occlusion shader`. nothing special. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3397495/blender_related/quantize_and_normalize.blend

Comment: @zeffii had a look around, this might be what you are looking for, I didn't go through it yet tho. http://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/41864

Comment: @iKlsR that does look promising!

Comment: <br>
One of the Techniques (UV Based) of the .Blend file on Blendswap is explained here
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zjhdGY21WqQ But it didnt work out for me, as the Lines get drawn in different Thickness acording to their Face-side ratio.<br>
With fairly even distributes equally sized Polygons its working quite good. Hope that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the mean time here's one workaround that doesn't require UVs:

Note that you have to activate Auto Smooth and set it to 0° (don't ask me why)

[image]

Answer (score 7):

As of yet it hasn't been implemented. Although there was no specific mention of improving the wireframe node, Thomas Dinges is working on some Cycles things this GSoC. I think it's just a matter of time before he, or another developer, gets to it.

Comment: quite right, I look forward to seeing something more convenient than the old methods.

Comment: The other answers don't look great rendered, I'm OK with this answer in the negative for now. I will submit an alternative but leave this one accepted.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you want(iKlsR also mentions this in the comments):
http://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/41864

The .blend file contains a wireframe shader for both quads and triangles.

Comment: Not only is this a [link answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) but the content is also behind a registration wall. Please include some info on how this shader works.