# Why does the wire-frame material fades across the object?

Tags: rendering, materials, wireframe

Why does the wire-frame material fades across the object?

Here is what I did - I created a new material and I selected on "Wire" and I made it shadeless. Then, I created a new material and assigned the new material on the on the object. However, doing it that way, it allows me to render both materials - "Wire" and "Surface". Then I get a fading result like this - 
[image]

But I want all of the edges to be shown, not a fading result. How can I make that?

Here is the blend file if anybody wants to check it out - 
http://www.pasteall.org/blend/31021

Comment: Could you post a .blend?

Comment: I was, but I forgot the website, how was it called?

Comment: I think this is because of the Z offset. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2784/599

Comment: I was playing with the Z-offset, but the same result continues.

Comment: @Vladimir http://www.pasteall.org/blend/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable Z transparency and increase the Z offset:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did try play with the offset, but I didn't go that extreme with it.