# Can freestyle render edges with no face?

Tags: rendering, freestyle, edges

I have a mesh with some *"faceless edges"*. **Can freestyle render them?**

Comment: Nope, I don't think this is supported. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3149/599 for alternatives.

Comment: Noooooo! My life has just become painful.

Comment: @gandalf3 Your answer is correct, do post it as an actual answer so it can be marked as such! (And generally please avoid answering questions through comments ;))

Comment: @SimonRepp lol, normally I'm the one asking someone to post their comment as an answer.. :P Thanks, answered :)

Comment: yes you can, [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/290903/165810) I've posted a simple workaround.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately [this isn't supported](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Freestyle#Known_Limitations_and_issues) (yet):

> ## Known Limitations and issues
>
> - FreeStyle is only available for the Blender Internal renderer.
> - Highly memory demanding: All mesh objects in a render layer are loaded at once.
> - **Only faced mesh objects are supported**. The following kinds of meshes are ignored.
>
>   - Mesh faces with wire materials.
>   - Mesh faces with completely transparent materials.
> - Transparent faces are treated as opaque faces.
> - No edges at face intersections are detected yet.
> - Layer masks do not work with Freestyle.
> - Freestyle rendering results do not have any Z depth information.
> - Does not work with a panoramic camera.

<sup>Emphasis mine. Note that Freestyle is available in the latest development builds and will be in 2.72.</sup>

Perhaps it will be supported someday, but for now you'll have to try something else. See [How can I render an edge only mesh as solid lines?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3149/599) for alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone reading this, Freestyle is supported in Cycles as of 2.79b (and I believe some earlier versions as well). I've been using it routinely with Cycles without a problem.

Comment: This is not an answer.