# How do you render lines in EEVEE/Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

I am trying to convert my workflow over to Cycles/EEVEE since the Blender Renderer will no longer be available.  A fair bit of my product is drawing lines or paths in the scene (such as below which depicts scattering off surfaces of the cube).  With the Blender Renderer I could create a mesh with no faces (only edges), and attach a Wire shader that was set Shadeless.  This worked perfectly. [image: Blender with shadeless wire material]

Alas, I can't seem to find a way to do this in Cycles/EEVEE.  Everything I have read talks about:

1. Use the wireframe node.  This only works if you are drawing borders on polygons, which I don't have.
2. Turn the wires into actual polygons.  Somewhat awkward as needed polygon width is dependent on distance to camera.
3. Use curves with a Bevel Depth (Really just #2 above).

Is there some way to get this effect in Cycles/EEVEE?  I have been putting off moving to Cycles because of this, and now Blender Renderer is disappearing.

Comment: Hi  I’m wondering if you ever worked out how to do this?

Comment: @Nathan Have you tried any of the solutions from this older question? Namely the skin modifier or "convert to curves" with a bevel? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3149/how-can-i-render-an-edge-only-mesh-as-solid-lines