# "Curve From Mesh/Text" not working on wireframe of cube

Tags: bezier-curves, edges, wireframe

I was following this link on [solidifying edges](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8300/how-to-solidify-edges). When I went to convert the mesh to a curve, nothing happened. Here's what I starting with a new file:

1. Select cube
2. <kbd>Tab</kbd> to edit mode
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> > Wireframe
4. <kbd>Tab</kbd> back to object mode
5. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> > Curve from Mesh/Text

Nothing happens. I noticed that it works if I add a Grid or Circle and try to convert those. What am I doing wrong?

I have Blender 2.71 (Release Candidate). I also tried converted the cube directly without converting it to a wireframe, but that didn't work either.

Context: I'm trying to create a picture like this, with shadeless faces (that occlude the background) and dark edges:

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9271/render-a-wireframe-with-equal-thickness-in-cycles

Comment: i've addressed the question anyway, but the answer to the thing you want to achieve is to use Freestyle render lines. You will need 2.72 upwards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Conversion to wireframe does this in essence, for every face on a Mesh.

[image]

The wireframe conversion transforms each face into thin faces interior to  the perimeter of the face, this function has parameters that you can change to adjust the width of those faces, but by default it is rather thin.

> As a side note: The Curve from Mesh/Text conversion tool operates best on Meshes if you remove the faces first. (X, [remove only faces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyDNK.png)). If the mesh doesn't have any Faces there is no need to convert to wire-frame (or remove doubles later on).

You can set the thickness of the wireframe to 0.000, and then you'll see little dots on the edges, because it still creates faces but they are so thin they will fall below the 'remove doubles' limit:

[image]

Removing doubles would look like this:

[image]

At this point you can *convert to Curve from Mesh/Text*. But I doubt that is actually what you want.

---

If you [follow the link in the first comment](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9271/render-a-wireframe-with-equal-thickness-in-cycles) on your Question you will be able to render results like this:

[image]

Conversion to wire-frame isn't the way to go about rendering with face occlusion.

Comment: The link you gave me did the trick! However, the original method you mentioned didn't work because when I deleted the faces, it deleted everything. Although it's not as important now, how should I delete the face in a way the keeps the edges/vertices? Do I need to first created edges/vertices?

Comment: read carefully what I said about the delete procedure, and look carefully at the options that appear in the delete menu. http://i.stack.imgur.com/hyDNK.png

Answer (score 3):

You could try this:

- Select the cube
- <kbd>Tab</kbd> to enter Edit Mode
- <kbd>Delete</kbd>, only faces
- <kbd>Tab</kbd> to exit Edit Mode
- <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> should convert the mesh to curve

I think you can only convert mesh to curve, if the mesh only consists of edges and vertices, because curves basically also has only edges and vertices

Comment: I already said this..